# Making Http Request to Local Computer from Android Emulator

Tags: android, angular2-routing, nativescript

I am using Visual Studio Emulator for Android. I have checked the network settings on my virtual android. My Desktop Adapter is 192.168.0.3 the other is 169.254.80.80.

I have tried in my config all three connections other posts have mentioned. This is not a duplicate because these three do not work.

> `http://10.0.2.2:52930/api/values/5`
>
> `http://192.168.0.3:52930/api/values/5`
>
> `http://169.254.80.80:52930/api/values/5`

I have verified my service is running and can be accessed from my local computer with `http://localhost:52930/api/values/5`

The error for `10.0.2.2` connection and `192.168.0.3` is

> {"originalStack":"Error: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.
>   2 (port 52930): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)\n    at ZoneAwar
>   eError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Groceries/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:
>   993:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Groceries/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/http/http-r
>   equest/http-request.js:44:34)

There is a much longer period of wait (about 2 minutes) before the `169.254.80.80` connection begins to show the above error.

I have disabled the windows firewall. I have no other firewalls. I have allowed Hyper-V application in the firewall just in case.

Any other suggestions?

**EDIT**

It appears to be an issue with the emulator. I opened up the browser in the emulator and typed in `http://headers.jsontest.com`

And it appears that it can't access that url. The error the emulators browser is reporting is.

> Webpage not available.
>   The webpage at http://headers.jsontest.com/ could not be loaded because:
>   `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: `Network is unreachable` and `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` sound like you don't have internet permissions enabled on your app/emulator

Comment: @cricket_007 well, if it isn't on by default that's dumb, but how would I go about turning it on?

Comment: You must enable internet  permission in the manifest xml

Comment: @cricket_007 I couldn't find any documentation on where it would be with Visual Studio Emulator, do you know where it would be?

Comment: I don't use those tools, but `AndroidManifest.xml` is not part of the emulator